# How to set up boost easily with clang with brew installation on OS X

Tags: c++, boost, clang, homebrew

I installed boost 1.60 via brew on OS X, El Capitan 10.11.4

```
> brew install boost
==> Downloading https://homebrew.bintray.com/bottles/boost-1.60.0_1.el_capitan.bottle.tar.gz
######################################################################## 100.0%
==> Pouring boost-1.60.0_1.el_capitan.bottle.tar.gz
  /usr/local/Cellar/boost/1.60.0_1: 11,139 files, 436.0M
```

However, it's not easy to use `<boost/...>` in my clang tool chains. It simply can't find the boost directory.

```
> make
Scanning dependencies of target foo
[ 50%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/foo.dir/foo.cpp.o
foo.cpp:16:10: fatal error: 'boost/type_index.hpp' file not found
#include <boost/type_index.hpp>
         ^
1 error generated.
```

I know that I have to set some environment variables or add `-I`. But I'd like to see the best way to resolve this problem for boost.

Comment: Is `/usr/local/Cellar' in your `$PATH`? Type echo $PATH to find out

Answer (score 0):

From the descriptions, I think there are two possible solutions for your problem

1. Install boost locally somewhere and set BOOST_ROOT variable to that folder.
2. Update boost's include and libraries variables to corresponding boost brew's directories.

Below is is the code segment that you need to add to your CMakeLists.txt

```
set(Boost_NO_SYSTEM_PATHS TRUE)
if (Boost_NO_SYSTEM_PATHS)
  set(BOOST_ROOT "${ROOT_DIR}/")
  set(BOOST_INCLUDE_DIRS "${ROOT_DIR}/include")
  set(BOOST_LIBRARY_DIRS "${ROOT_DIR}/lib")
endif (Boost_NO_SYSTEM_PATHS)
```